Seeking Recommendations on Quantum Attacks
I'm exploring quantum attacks (in the Q1 model) on symmetric structures, including hash functions, block ciphers, modes of operation and stream ciphers with time complexity beyond quadratic speedup. I've found a couple of resources:  Link1, link2 and Link3. I’d appreciate any additional recommendations you might have. Thank you!

Does this answer your question? https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/17726/10454

Maybe also consider asking at crypto.stackexchange.com (and adding a   Comment here and there that you’re cross posting)…
